# Analytics API : Number of visits between two dates with specific time

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to be using the php google analytics api to get the number of visits on my website between two dates **with specific time** :
for instance from the 2013-12-25 at 4pm to 2013-13-26 at 8am.

Currently my code looks like that

```
$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
$results = $service->data_ga->get('ga:35779548', '2013-12-25', '2013-12-26','ga:visits');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported directly, but you could add the `ga:date` and `ga:hour` dimensions and sum the values that fall in your date range.

Answer (score 0):

If it can benefit to anyone, here is my code, for a given date, following the advice here:

```
  //$date YYYY-MM-DD , $hour : until that hour (1 to 23)
  function MyNumberOfVisits($date,$hour){

global $service,$viewID;

if ($hour==null)
{
    $results = $service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$viewID, $date, $date,'ga:visits');
    return $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
}
else
{
    $dimensions = 'ga:hour'; 
    $results = $service->data_ga->get('ga:'.$viewID, $date, $date,'ga:visits',array('dimensions' => $dimensions) );
    $rows=$results['rows'];
    $total=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<=$hour;$i++)
    {
        $visit_at_jour=$rows[$i][1];
        //echo "$i  $visit_at_jour <br>";
        $total+=$visit_at_jour;
    }
    return $total;
}
```

}